# preview images before upload and then upload into the server in asp mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, image, upload

I made a form with one input and some preview box.
when user select own image , image load in the preview pox correctly but after submit I dont know how to send the image in the image box into the server.

here is the script that I user for get and load image into the clientside image box.

```
function readURL(input) {

if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: Create a form and submit it

Comment: try this http://www.dotnetspan.com/2014/11/upload-image-using-multipart-in-mvc5.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to upload cropped images to the serve then this is the link you have to follow

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Crop-and-Upload-Image-with-Thumbnail-using-jQuery-and-HTML5-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a form and place file uploader and upload button inside form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Home", FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
   <input type="file" name="file" id="fileUploader" />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="btnFileUpload" />
 }
```

On click of upload button uploaded image will be submited to the controller action.

Controller Code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var uploadedfile = Request.Files[0];
            //save file logic

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```